# How to change 7 textview values at a time by clicking one imageButton 12 times in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, textview, settext

Sorry for this Silly question, actually i am new in Android... 
Actually I have 7 Text Views and 1 image button on my screen, i want when i click on image Button then all text values changed(as i want text), remember that all text values are different from each other and then i again click on image Button then text value again change (as i want text) and it's run up-to 12 times and change values of text views by click image Button on 12 times. 
if you know it can done by and Array then plz comment.

```
  My XML:
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/pictitle
    android:onClick="nextText"  />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java:

```
     public class MyProject extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_pics);
}

public void indexPics(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void nextText(View view) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to instantiate all your TextView's and then use the setText() method to change their text.

```
textView1.setText("One");
```

The other way is to get all the TextViews as child of your parent layout (like LinearLayout or the one you are using and using getChildAt method)

```
LinearLayout ll = //Your Layout this can be any Linear or Relative layout 
                 //in which you added your spinners at runtime ;

int count = ll.getChildCount();
for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
{
    View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof TextView)
    {
        // you got the spinner
        EditText s = (EditText) v;
        if(s.getID() == R.id.textView1){
            textView1.setText("One");
        }
    }
}
```

The first one is easier and simpler. I prefer this. Hope I helped. :)

EDIT - Supoose on first click of the button you want the TextViews to have name of days and ont the next it displays numbers, the code will be:

```
 //You can also use List here
 String [] days = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
 String [] nums = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};

 //Your method to update the TextViews
 public void updateTextViews(String [] texts){
         textView1.setText(texts[0]);
         textView2.setText(texts[1]);
         textView3.setText(texts[2]);
         textView4.setText(texts[3]);
         textView5.setText(texts[4]);
         textView6.setText(texts[5]);
         textView7.setText(texts[6]);
 }

 //Count the number of clicks, (or the condition on which you want to change the text displayed)
 int counter = 1;

 //your ImageBUtton's onClick() method
 @override
 public void onClick(View v){

    //Check the click count (or your condition)
    switch(counter){
        case 1: //first click
           updateTextViews(days);
           break;
        case 2: //second click
           updateTextViews(nums);
           break;
        default:
           //This is executed when no case matches. 
           break;
    } 
    **counter = counter + 1;**      
 }
```

Comment: Atul O Holic: by using textView1.setText("One"); i can change my textview value only one time but i mention that above i want to change 12 times and on every time when i click on Imagebutton .

Comment: Atul O Holic: can u send me complete code with array please?

Comment: Please see now. I have edited it again. You will have to modify this as per your requirement.

Comment: Not working perfectly, it change textviews only by clicking first time, nothing happend when i click 2nd time.

Comment: I think i need to make 7 Arrays for 7 textViews and run it 12 times from 0 to 11. Right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Hence I used a counter to check how many times the Button gets clicked. You can put a switch case there to check for values from 1 - 12. Also, if you don't want to use those array later then you can use the same array by replacing its value.

Comment: Hehe, spoon feeding. :) Added a switch case too. Please see the edit.

Comment: Haha, i am not spoon feeder, i am beginner.
Let me apply your code.

Comment: So sorry, missed on a small piece. Please add counter = counter + 1; the way I added above. This will increment the click value.

Comment: @ Atul O Holic: After applying your code something goes wrong and when i click on nextButton it show crash message i.e. "Unfortunately, Appname has stopped".
Remember that my next button on click method name was public void nextText(View view) {

   }. and you mention in this code is public void onClick(View v) {

   }

Comment: Put all the code of onClick in your nextText method and try. Also, post the code you are trying now.

Comment: @ Atul O Holic: By using your code with little bit changing method name,Finally i get that's i actually want and also i clicked right marked on your code.Thanks Alott!!!

Comment: So glad to hear that. We have been tackling alot on this. :) Credits to you as you were the one implementing. Cheers. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Adnan - just wanted to check if you got the concept of using methods? Let me know.

Comment: yes, after concentration of the Code i got this method now.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int getIdByName(final String name) {
    try {
        final Field field = R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);

        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
final TextView[] txts= new TextView[7];

for (int i = 0; i < txts.length; i++) {
    txts[i] = (TextView) findViewById(getIdByName("textView" + (i + 1)));
}
```

And then use a list String to set text of them

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    txts[i].setText(StringList[i]);
}
```

Comment: @MM-BB +1 this is correct ans. Only one correction i found. You can use `txts[i].setText(StringList[i]);` is better inside second for loop.

Comment: Okay, can i place all this code in one place or separate as showing above at three different places ?

Comment: Still not find Correct Solution, plz any body read my Question Description carefully and upload the Correct Code that i want...

Comment: @MM-BB Great job dude. Happy coding.

Comment: getting error in 3rd line of your fist code
i.e. "Field"
 final Field field = R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);
i should import this "Field" word?

Comment: and also getting on last line of your 3rd code.
Error detail:
Multiple markers at this line
 - StringList cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
        - txts cannot be resolved to a 
  variable

Comment: @MM-BB i have import field as import java.text.Format.Field;
but now it showing error on R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);
what i need to modify this line, how i can fix it?

Comment: Check my Update answer. change getIdByName("txt" + (i + 1)) to getIdByName("textView" + (i + 1))

Comment: i have Error in this line:
R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);

Comment: @MM-BB: plz print any value in text view, like "abc", "def" i can change it as i want because i did n't get functionality of your code and facing some error.You just print first and second click values in one or two textviews, rest of the values i print myself by copying your code.

Comment: Use String[] StringList = {"text for textView1" , "text for textView2" , "text for textView3" , "text for textView4" , "text for textView5" , "text for textView6" , "text for textView7"  };

Comment: Same again, i have Error in this line: R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
public class MyProject extends Activity {
 TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6, tv7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.my_pics);
 tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
 tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
 tv5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
 tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
 tv7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
}

public void indexPics(View v) {
 Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
}

public void nextText(View view) {
  tv1.setText("1");
  tv2.setText("2");
  tv3.setText("3");
  tv4.setText("4");
  tv5.setText("5");
  tv6.setText("6");
  tv7.setText("7");
   }
  }
```

Comment: krishna, first we need to write findViewById, instead of findfindViewById and the second thing is that by applying your code i have change my textview value only one time but i mention that above i want to change 12 times and on every time when i click on Imagebutton, the text values will be change 12 times by pressibg button.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other posts: You could just use a global integer to keep track of your buttons state. In your onClick you add 1 to that integer, and depending on the integer value you can set the text to your textfields in a switch case. You would have 12 cases, so it won't look too nice, but that might be the easiest solution.

```
switch(yourInteger)
{
    case 1:    textView1.setText(array1[0])
               textView2.setText(array2[0])
               ...

    case 2:    textView1.setText(array1[1])
               ...
}
```

...and so on.

```
     public class MyProject extends Activity {

Button yourButton;
int buttonState;
String[] array1;
String[] array2;
//other arrays


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_pics);

    buttonState = 0;
    yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
}

public void indexPics(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void nextText(View view) {

   }
}

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 

                buttonState++;

                TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                //do the same for the other textviews here

                switch(buttonState)
                {
                    case 1: 
                           try{
                               Log.d("OnClick", "tv1 value on first click: "+array1[0]);
                           }catch(Exception e){}
                           //textView1.setText(array1[0]);
                           //textView2.setText(array2[0]);
                           textView1.setText("tv1: 1st click");
                           textView2.setText("tv2: 1st click");
                           //other textview here
                           break;
                    case 2:
                           try{
                               Log.d("OnClick", "tv1 value on second click: "+array1[1]);
                           }catch(Exception e){}
                           //textView1.setText(array1[1]); 
                           textView1.setText("tv1: 2nd click");
                           //other textviews here
                           break;
                    case 3: //and so on for all 12 states. Also dont forget:
                    ...
                    case 12:
                            buttonState = 0;
                }



    }   
});
```

You also have to put the text in your arrrays somewhere.

Comment: tritop: can u plz upload complete code for this program?

Comment: @Adnan: I edited with some more code. That should be enough to give you an idea.

Comment: @ tritop:this line give me error "yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()" 
i need to add implements View.OnClickListener or implements View.OnsetClickListener in Class?

Comment: Of course you would need to do View.OnClickListener or just import it:
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: @ tritop:can u plz print any value in textviews, like "abc", "def" i can change it as i want because i did n't get functionality of your code and facing some error.You just print first and second click values in one or two textviews, rest of the values i print myself by copying your code.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know if you have the right strings? Then see the updated code, I included some Log messages, allowing you to see the values in Logcat. Or don't you get any value because you cant initialize the arrays? You could just replace the arrays at the switch case like this: 'case 1: textView1.setText("first click");'  
'case 2: textView1.setText("second click");' (also updated that in the code above)

Comment: tritop: Unfortunately, App has stopped, the reason is that i have mixed two method, one is onClick() method created by add unimplement method and other has ImageButton onClick nextText() method.
i have two button i.e. one for goto MainActivity and other for going to nextText but in whole you can't make any code inside public void nextText(View view) {

   }